# rails devise edit_user_registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise for authentication in my rails app. I am able to sign in and out and also sign up. However once the user is signed in, I want to provide a means for the user to modify his sign in password. For that the app provides a link to the **'edit_user_registration_path'** which is shown in the rake routes output below.

When the user clicks on the modify password link below,

```
<li><%= link_to "Change Password", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
```

I get the following error

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}):
```

I have a UsersController with show, edit and update actions. The edit action is to update the other columns of the Users model.

The routes are set up as below

```
devise_for :users
resources  :users, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
```

rake route output -

```
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
       user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
   user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                     PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                     DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
           edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)      users#edit
                user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
                     PUT    /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
                root        /                              home#index
```

The console log is below

```
Started GET "/users/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-21 15:21:38 +0530
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#edit as HTML
 User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
 Rendered devise/registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (15.9ms)
 Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
 Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
 Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (42.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 99ms

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}):
app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:22:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb__267315279__621159918'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:20:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__982964301_89714280'
```

Comment: Could you show us:

app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:22

Comment: I believe you are calling edit_user_path on its own, with out telling it which user to edit.

Comment: As you guessed, I am using edit_user_path. Anything wrong with this? how to indicate the user here? <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path %></li>

Comment: @Leito, As you suggested I modified edit_user_path by adding the user to edit, and everything is working fine. edit_user_path(current_user). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important lines in the logs above are:

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}):
>       app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:22:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb__267315279__621159918'

Routes need to match with all it's params, in this case

```
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)      users#edit
```

is not matched when no :id is supplied.

Instead of:

```
<%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path %>
```

Send the `current_user` as a parameter:

```
<%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %>
```

Comment: I am accepting your answer since your comment above fixed the problem.